# Get type member's MemberInfo without iteration of all type members

Tags: c#, reflection

I have written some version of the following method in a dozen different solutions:

```
//Get the string specified in the "Description" attribute of an enum value
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumVal) where T : Enum
{
    var type = enumVal.GetType();
    var member = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString()).First();
    var attrib = member.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
    return attrib?.Description ?? null;
}
```

Given this enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("The First")]  TheFirst,
    [Description("The Second")] TheSecond
}
```

I am then able to write the following code:

```
MyEnum.TheFirst.GetDescription()
>> "The First"
```

This method works and it's the only way I've seen people do it. Here's my question:

How can I get the `MemberInfo` without using `Type.GetMember()` to iterate the type members to match a string? If the input (`MyEnum.TheFirst`) is already a strongly qualified member, why does reflection require me to abandon that and essentially search for the member as a string?

The code I *want* to write is:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumVal) where T : Enum
{
    var member = enumVal.GetMember(); //gets the fully qualified MemberInfo object
    var attrib = member.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
    return attrib?.Description ?? null;
}
```

I'm aware that I could write an extension method to do this, but it wouldn't solve the fundamental issue: that I have to use a `string` search (again, via the `System.Reflection.GetMember(string name)` method) just to get information that should already be readily available.

Please let me know if I'm thinking about this the wrong way, or if there's another, simpler approach to this.

Comment: Sounds something like `infoof` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue/.

Comment: @thehennyy That's a great link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer "why not" questions, so let's think about what would be required for your desired feature to exist instead. It would have to be thought of, designed, implemented, tested, and documented. That's a good amount of effort that could be spent on higher priority features that will provide a higher impact and greater usefulness to the user.

Is this a high priority feature? Do people want to get the type member of an enum from its current value most of the time? Is this something that they couldn't easily do with the existing reflection API?

I would tend to say no to all of those, particularly because you can achieve what you want to do in two lines of code with no apparent loss of productivity or performance.

Additionally, think about this from the perspective of designing the reflection method to get the member in the first place. You want to be able to get *any* member from *any* type, not just an enum. You want to support the most useful and most general case to provide the greatest value to the user, so the most straightforward way to get the member is by its name. That means searching for a string.

Are there enough cases where the user wants to pass an enum value and get its corresponding member, and so much so that there needs to be a special case to support enums without going through the standard name search API? I would also tend to say no to that as well.

Comment: I'll call this the answer in addition to @thehennyy's link posted in response to my question. It's not particularly satisfying in a language that, usually, has satisfying ways to accomplish most things, but I think I have a better idea why that feature isn't there (and, most likely, won't be).

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to specify that the only passed in `Enum` values will be from `Enum`s declared with the defaults, so it is based on `Int32` and sequential values, you can do:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumVal) where T : Enum {
    var type = enumVal.GetType();
    var memberInfo = type.GetFields()[1+Convert.ToInt32(enumVal)];
    var attrib = memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
    return attrib?.Description ?? null;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting!  I'm curious how this would perform comparatively.

Comment: @Daniel Looking at the code for `Convert.ToInt32` as applied to a lambda value, it is certainly more than a cast. If you could write `GetDescription` for a specific enum (i.e. non-generic), you could just use a cast which would require no code, but the call requires boxing `enumVal` so there is overhead.